# BigCommerce Edit Estimated Shipping Cost Returned by FedEX Webservices

Tags: web-services, api, bigcommerce, fedex

Big Commerce allows it's store owners to integrate FedEx web services into their stores to provide estimated shipping costs to their customers. I'm curious if there's a way to use Big Commerce's API to make changes to what this estimated cost of shipping is.

Say for instance, a customer wants to estimate what the shipping costs will be through FedEx and FedEx returns $10.00. I want to be able to increase it by 30% so that it displays as somewhere around $13.00.

I know this might seem like an odd request, but I've asked Big Commerce Support and they've said it should be possible, however I'm not seeing any way to do it through their API